# Networking between Docker containers

Tags: docker-container, docker-network

I have a docker container 'A' on a host 10.11.12.13 listening on port 0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp
I have another container 'B' on same host how wants to talk to 'A' on 8443 via host. 
Thus when I run command curl https://10.11.12.13:8443 inside B it gives me error as 'No route to host' but I can ping 10.11.12.13 successfully. 
I am not sure what else I am missing?

Can someone help regarding the issue?

Answer (score 0):

For this, You need to address the host using container name.

Say container name which you want to hit is container_name1 and Port you want to hit is 8443. You can run using container_name1:8443